# Css vertically center explained

Tags: css

Can someone please provide an explanation as to how the following styling results in text becoming vertically centered? For example, why are we using `position: absolute` if we're centering relative to a parent? Why is `top: 50%` being used? Thanks!

```
    .vertical-center {
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Comment: there is no context in your question. Needs details and clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: absolute` takes an element out of the document flow and lets you position it in relation to the next higher ancestor which has `position: relative`, usually (and intentionally) overlapping other elements (for example text over an image).

`top: 50%` moves the top of the absolutely positioned element 50% down, i.e. half of the parent's height. That way the top border of the child element will be at the exact center of the parent.

`transform: translateY(-50%);` moves the absolutely positioned element 50% *up*, but this time 50% of *its own* height, above the vertical center of the parent element, resulting in exact vertical centering inside the parent.

All this only works if the parent has `position: relative`, so it can serve as a position anchor for the absolutely positioned child.

The same goes for horizontal centering, using `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%);`

Combined (i.e. horizontally and vertically) that would be `top: 50%; left: 50%` and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!